# xfs_repair , complain about contains a mounted and writable filesystem

Tags: rhel, filesystems, kernel, xfs

Since we have the following from dmesg

```
[37785.390633] XFS (dm-2): Metadata corruption detected at xfs_dir3_block_read_verify+0x5e/0x110 [xfs], block 0x7f8af18
[37785.390634] XFS (dm-2): Unmount and run xfs_repair

Dm-2 is the /var
```

We start to perform the xfs_repair according to the document - https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1194613

First we force umount on /var

```
umount -l /var
```

and the we start the procedure according to - https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1194613

```
xfs_repair -v /dev/mapper/vg_var 2>&1  |tee /tmp/xfs_repair.out
xfs_repair: /dev/mapper/vg_var contains a mounted filesystem
xfs_repair: /dev/mapper/vg_var contains a mounted and writable filesystem
fatal error -- couldn't initialize XFS library
```

as we can see from above xfs_repair is complain about `/dev/mapper/vg_var` contains a mounted file-system
 , in spite we force the umount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have asked for a lazy unmount (`umount -l`). This will only unmount the filesystem when there are no more processes accessing it. The documentation (`man umount`) itself says

> **`-l`** Lazy unmount. Detach the filesystem from the filesystem hierarchy now, and cleanup all references to the filesystem as soon as it is not busy anymore.

In this scenario you shouldn't use the `-l` flag because you need to be sure the filesystem really is unmounted.

Verify that the filesystem really is unmounted before proceeding. If you have `lsof` that may help identify the unexpected processes.